# ESRI forms using hooks

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, vb.net, windows

This has been bugging me for a while. I can easily call a form from a button using `ShowDialog()` if I use standard vb.net windows form. However when I use the ESRI addin dockable window which uses hooks in the form I can't seem to open it.

It requires a 'hook as object' when I try to call it from a button. ESRI forms do not use the `ShowDialog()` method and require you to use `Show()`. I have searched and look everywhere but can't see how to call the form that uses hooks. Do I need to create a new hook object in the button class?

When I click the button nothing happens and it turns grey. The form is not hidden behind ArcMap or anything.

Here is what I use to call the form:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnClick()
    Dim oform As New window(Me.Hook)
    oform.Show()

End Sub
```

Here is the ESRI form

```
Public Class window

Public Sub New(ByVal hook As Object)


     InitializeComponent()


    Me.Hook = hook
End Sub


Private m_hook As Object

Public Property Hook() As Object
 Get
  Return m_hook
End Get
Set(ByVal value As Object)
  m_hook = value
End Set
End Property

Public Class AddinImpl
Inherits ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.DockableWindow

Private m_windowUI As window

Protected Overrides Function OnCreateChild() As System.IntPtr
  m_windowUI = New window(Me.Hook)
  Return m_windowUI.Handle
End Function

Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal Param As Boolean)
  If m_windowUI IsNot Nothing Then
    m_windowUI.Dispose(Param)
  End If

  MyBase.Dispose(Param)
End Sub

  End Class

End Class
```

UPDATE:

Now I tried

```
Dim dockWindow As ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IDockableWindow

    Dim dockWinID As UID = New UIDClass()
    dockWinID.Value = My.ThisAddIn.IDs.window
    dockWindow = My.ArcMap.DockableWindowManager.GetDockableWindow(dockWinID)

    dockWindow.Show(True)
```

And still does not work.

Comment: The hook is a reference to the application (e.g. `ArcMap`). But I think the idea is to use the `IDockableWindowManager` interface of the application object: call `GetDockableWindow()` and then `Show()` on the returned `IDockableWindow` instance.

Comment: Sorry, the hook should be `ArcMap.Application`, not `ArcMap`.

Comment: I tried the `GetDockableWindow()` method above and the button still does not work.

Comment: See my answer below, I just tried it, and can confirm that it works.

Comment: I am trying it from your answer using vb.net. If you see the new code I have written in the update above it does not work. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: Could you elaborate on *Does not work*? Does GetDockableWindow return something (put a breakpoint on that line)? What I did was to create a brand new addin with a button and a dockablewindow. I didn't change any of the default settings. The code from my answer is in the button's click event.

Comment: It returns nothing. When I click on it in ArcMap the button just greys out. No error messages or anything. I even have a Try and catch statement in the `Onclick` method. I am sure your code works in C# but when I try the code I wrote above doesn't even though its based on `getDockableWindow()` The code above is also in the click event

Comment: Then something else must be wrong. Try to create a new addin to see if you can get a dockablewindow working.

Comment: It works now. Please see my answer below. Though you were right that I had to use `GetDockableWindow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a complete sample that shows how to use the DockableWindowManager (C#, sorry):

```
var w = ArcMap.DockableWindowManager.GetDockableWindow(new UIDClass { Value = ThisAddIn.IDs.DockableWindow1 });
if (w != null)
{
    w.Show(true);
}
```

In VB.Net, the ID's are in My.ThisAddIn.IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Seems I had to assign my dockwindow to Nothing before I use the getDockableWindow() method. Also had to change show() method.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnClick()

    Try

        ' Only get/create the dockable window if it's not there

        Dim dockWindow As ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IDockableWindow

        dockWindow = Nothing

        If dockWindow Is Nothing Then
            Dim dockWinID As UID = New UIDClass()
            dockWinID.Value = My.ThisAddIn.IDs.window
            dockWindow = My.ArcMap.DockableWindowManager.GetDockableWindow(dockWinID)
        End If

        dockWindow.Show((Not dockWindow.IsVisible()))


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```